# How to detect url in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have chat in Angular JS. I need to open dialog window if user put URL like as:
`/chat/dialog/12`

How I can do it?

Comment: why you don't think of modal popup instead of window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`$location`**. `$location.path()` returns the current URL

```
var url = $location.path();
if(url==='/chat/dialog/12'){
//do your code here
}
```

Comment: But if instead /12 any number?

Comment: I don't know what your scenario is. Getting URL is in this way. Comparing the URL with some string you want is your logic. Do you want to compare only `/chat/dialog/` ?